# Infinispan synchronization timeout exception

Tags: timeout, jboss7.x, infinispan, jgroups

I'm afraid I'm a little bit of a noob at this, but here goes.

I have an issue with Infinispan and timeout during synch.
I'm running two instances of JBoss AS7 with Infinispan 5.2.7-FINAL. TCP for synch.

Sometimes when deleting an entry from a cache on one of the nodes, the synchronization seems to fail, but checking the log on both nodes tells med the entry is gone and all the required cleanup involved from application side (tearing down Camel routes, etc) has been done. The initiating node claims to time-out when notifying it's peer:

```
09:53:33,182 INFO  [ConfigurationService] (http-/10.217.xx.yy:8080-3) ConfigurationService: deleteSmsAccountConfigurationData: got smsAccountID of SmsAccountIdentifier{smsAccountId=tel:46xxxxxx}

09:53:33,183 INFO  [com.ex.control.throttling.controller.ThrottlingService] (http-/10.217.xx.yy:8080-3) ThrottlingService: deleteThrottleForResource: deleting throttle from resource tel:46xxxxxx

09:53:45,232 INFO  [com.ex.control.routing.startup.DynamicRouteBootStrap] (OOB-21,smapexs01-54191) DynamnicRouteBootStrap: stopRoute: Attempting to stop sendSmppRoute: sendsmpproutetel:46xxxxxx recieveSmppRoute: recievesmpproutetel:46xxxxxx

09:53:45,233 INFO  [org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy] (OOB-21,smapexs01-54191) Starting to graceful shutdown 1 routes (timeout 300 seconds)

09:53:45,235 INFO  [org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy] (Camel (camel-2) thread #1 - ShutdownTask) Route: sendsmpproutetel:46xxxxxx shutdown complete, was consuming from: Endpoint[direct://tel:46xxxxxx]

09:53:45,235 INFO  [org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy] (OOB-21,smapexs01-54191) Graceful shutdown of 1 routes completed in 0 seconds

09:53:48,190 ERROR [org.infinispan.interceptors.InvocationContextInterceptor] (http-/10.217.xx.yy:8080-3) ISPN000136: Execution error: org.infinispan.CacheException: org.jgroups.TimeoutException: timeout sending message to smapexs03-38104
```

On this node it takes less than a second (I guess) to tear it down, on the other node it takes 6 seconds, is there a timeout of say 5 seconds somewhere that I have overseen?

I've searched this forum and others, but have not been able to sort it out.

Like I said, I'm a bit of a noob, I hope this makes sense to you. Anything that points me in the right direction is very welcome!

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: Yeah, there is a cache synchronous replication timeout defined somewhere. It all depends which cache this is, what it's used for...etc. Normally, the caches are defined in standalone/configuration/standalone.xml or standalone-ha.xml. In there, there's a cache section, and the xsd associated tells you how to set a cache's timeout if the attribute not already present in the XML file.

Comment: Thanks! Found a timeout of 6 s in the standalone-ha.xml. Remains to be seen if it is the one.